# Index Array with TimSort in C#

Tags: c#, .net, timsort

I was looking into the "timsort" algorithm for doing some sorting on my fairly large data sets: 
http://timsort4net.codeplex.com/

Typically I use `Array.Sort(Keys, Items)` where Items is an integer array that serves as a method to identify the position changes that occurred during the sort.

Is there any way to acheive this same result without having to heavily modify the implementation of the sorting algorithm?

Comment: I can't understand your problem why you think you should change available sorting algorithm?

Comment: I don't think I need to change the algorithm its self, just the implementation so I can take an integer array along for the ride.

Comment: You can use current implementation without any change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [extension method](http://timsort4net.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9920#117964) defined on IList

```
public static void TimSort<T>(this IList<T> array, Comparison<T> comparer, bool buffered = true)
```

to sort the list of indices, and pass in a Comparison that references the real objects given the indices, compares them and returns negative, positive or zero values.

Hope this helps!